# Registered trademark symbol doesn't show in compiled PDF

Tags: symbols

I am trying to get the registered trademark symbol by doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document} 

Trying to put registered trade mark symbol in\textregistered

\end{document}
```

But when I compile my document with TeXniCenter and look at the PDF there is just blank white space where the symbol should be.

Compilation method is LaTeX -> PS -> PDF. I am viewing with Adobe reader.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{textcomp}` to your preamble and see if that helps.  Otherwise, revise your question so it contains a minimal(!) example for others to test.

Comment: I have \usepackage{textcomp} in preamble. Still doesn't work

Comment: As you might suppose, 'still doesn't work' is not actually a useful description for almost any kind of computer problem.  A [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528), however, is useful.

Comment: @Cole: Please edit this intto your question. Indent the code by four space, or press the `{}` button after marking the code, in order to format it correctly. Also you should state how you compile the PDF exactly, e.g. are you simply using `pdflatex` or something else.

Comment: OK, so minimal an example is good.  Unfortunately, I have no problems with this file: I can see the symbol using `evince`, `mupdf`, `zathura`, and Adobe's `acroread` (all on Linux).  So it may be the compilation method, as suggested, or the viewer you are using.  Can you add these details?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with Windows, but perhaps you can try adding the line `\usepackage{lmodern}` or installing the CM-Super package (if it is not already installed).  It seems like you are using a 'bad' font (although `\textregistered` as a faked version that should work even with the default fonts, I think).

Comment: @jon Would you like to write an answer?